# Click with AXTitle

Tags: applescript

[image]I have the following script to automate logging into GlobalProtect. I could get the userID and Password but am unable to click on Sign In. I have used the AXTitle with the following and unable to get any where.

The only thing that worked was clicking on the button coordinates but I don't want to depend on the coordinates as that might not be fixed so want to see if I can get the button details and click on it.

These are the few things I have tried

`click button with "Sign In" of front window` and `click menu bar item 3 of menu bar 2`

Any hints on how to get the Sign In button

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `click button with "Sign In" of front window` changing the code to  `click button 2 of window 1` did the trick

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).